# Insert button connectivity

Tags: java, database, ms-access

I am developing a java program, backend : MS Access . I have written the code there no error or Exception, all other buttons are working fine .

Only the button "insert" (used for inserting into database from GUI) is not working .. no error is shown by net beans .

```
         b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
            {
                String fname=t1.getText();
                String lname=t2.getText();
                String age=t3.getText();

                try{
                    rs.moveToInsertRow();//moves cursor to new row

                    rs.updateString("Fname", fname);
                    rs.updateString("Lname", lname);
                    rs.updateString("age", age);
                    rs.insertRow();

                    //close two variable
                    st.close();
                    rs.close();
                catch(Exception ex){

                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please show us `moveToInsertRow()`, `updateString()` and `insertRow()`. If you don't have anything in your `catch` block net beans won't show anything. At least print the exception to screen.

Comment: By looking at the code, we have least to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Add **ex.printStackTrace();** in your catch block.

   ```
                   //close two variable
                   st.close();
                   rs.close();
               catch(Exception ex){
                     ex.printStackTrace();

               }
   ```
2. Run you application and try to insert a record
3. This will throw the error message and because of this new code it will display the complete exception stack trace in your console or log.

You may able to find the problem from the error message. If not paste the error message to the community for further help.